# Why doesn't the compiler infer T(interface) to be class that implements T when having double bounded generic type?

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

I have a class CBound that implements two interfaces IBound1 and Ibound2:

```
class CBound implements IBound1, IBound2 {}
```

I have a generic method that accept as type parameter a class type that implements both IBound1 and Ibound2 interfaces:

```
 public static <T extends IBound1 & IBound2> void getData(T list) {
      //Some code...
}
```

I made an object of type IBound1 with the imlementation of CBound class:

```
 IBound1 a = new CBound();
 getData(a); // doesn't work
```

Why the obj a is not working as a parameter for getData() ?

When I change the code with :

```
CBound b = new CBound();
getData(b); // It works fine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has to infer a `T` that satisfies the bounds *at compile time*.

When you pass in `a`, all that the compiler knows is that `a` is of type `IBound1`. Since the method's parameter is also `T`, the compiler only really have two choices of `T` here - `IBound1` or `Object` - neither of which satisfy the bounds.

You might ask, "why doesn't the compiler infer `T` to be `CBound` then?" Well there isn't anything in the expression `getData(a)` that is of type `CBound`. Even though we know that `a` actually refers to an object of type `CBound` by reading the previous lines of code, the compiler doesn't consider that when inferring `T`. And even if `T` were inferred to be `CBound`, you would not be able to pass `a` to a parameter of type `CBound`.

In the case of `b` however, the compiler knows very well that `b` is of type `CBound` (because you have declared it so), so it can successfully infer `T` to be `CBound`.

Comment: Exactly as @Sweeper said. I would just add that when the compiler statically analyzes your code doesn't know that `a` is `CBound`, which is the dynamic type of the object, it just knows the static type `IBound1`. It would work if you typecast it. `getData((CBound) a)`

Comment: " ...you would not be able to pass a to a parameter of type CBound" - I didn't get this to well

Comment: `a` is of type `IBound1` (as far as the compiler is concerned). If `T` were `CBound`, the parameter type of `getData` would be `CBound` too. You can't pass an expression to a parameter when that parameter's type is the expression's subtype. Like how you can't pass a `List` to a method accepting `ArrayList`.